# subtract data of different 1st column and 2nd column, showing its answer in 3rd column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on inventory management system. I don't know much about database quires.
How to subtract data of 1st column with 2nd column and showing its result in 3rd column. For Example i am trying

```
Total Quantity      Use Packets          Remaining Packets
     300                50                    250
     250                10                    240
     240                40                    200
```

and so on..

*the first column must contain the value of 3rd column. This all work has to be done in SQL database in visual studio.* 
Hope so you understand my question.

Comment: Yes your question is understandable, but very very basic, what have you tried?  Also what is your data table structure?  Did you try anything?

Comment: And there was no way to find this answer on the internet before asking here?
You could for examle use ANY SQL toutorial and take a look at page 1...

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    DECLARE @InventoryTotal AS TABLE
    ( 
      Quantity INT,
      UsePackets INT
    )
   INSERT INTO @InventoryTotal
   SELECT 300, 50 UNION ALL                  
   SELECT 250, 10 UNION ALL                 
   SELECT 240, 40    

   SELECT * FROM @InventoryTotal

    SELECT  Quantity,
            UsePackets ,
            (Quantity-UsePackets) AS RemainingPackets  
    FROM @InventoryTotal
    ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

Result

```
Quantity    UsePackets  RemainingPackets
---------------------------------------
300             50          250
250             10          240
240             40          200
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by coding if you are in Visual Studio.
In my example I have a table called Data with the Columns **TotalQuantity**, **UsePackets** and **RemainingPackets**. I can update the Column RemainingPackets like this:

```
    using (var context = new PlutoContext())
        {

            foreach (var contextData in context.Datas)
            {
                contextData.RemainingPackets = contextData.TotalQuantity - contextData.UsePackets;
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```